# Laravel API : "Error: certificate has expired" though certificate is active

Tags: laravel, api, ssl

I'm getting this error today while API was working fine yesterday. Website is working fine and SSL is still active

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I send the request to example.com without `www` I get the same error and also get `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`

Comment: Seems like the next place to look would be the "details" tab of the cert?  Or the "certification path"?  :-). Maybe related? https://calnetweb.berkeley.edu/calnet-technologists/incommon-sectigo-certificate-service/addtrust-external-root-expiration-may-2020

Comment: "This certificate is OK" That's what I get. I tested the API using apitester.com and it's working fine I don't get this error!!!